# How do I get it to close when clicking on a cell?

Tags: javascript

I have created a list and I want to know how I can do so that when I click on one of the cells in the list this cell is eliminated, can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Add your list and your code. there we have many type of implementations. we cant identify your implementations method unless you post it properly. 
add your code and a screenshot of your list

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> razasdeperro = new ArrayList<>();

    razasdeperro.add("Pastor Aleman");
    razasdeperro.add("Gran Danes");
    razasdeperro.add("chihuahua");
    razasdeperro.add("braco");
    razasdeperro.add("pointer");
    razasdeperro.add("Pastor Aleman");
    razasdeperro.add("Gran Danes");
    razasdeperro.add("chihuahua");
    razasdeperro.add("braco");
    razasdeperro.add("pointer");
```

RecyclerView recyclerViewdogs=findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewdogs);
recyclerViewdogs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).